# Powershell - trying to merge 2 result in 1 txt/csv

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a daily script to check status of list of URLS and pinging servers.

I've tried to combine the csv, however, the output of $status code is different from the one in csv

```
$pathIn = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\URLList.txt"
$URLList = Get-Content -Path $pathIn
$names = gc "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\hostnames.txt"

#status code
$result = foreach ($uri in $URLList) {
    try {
        $res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -Method Head -TimeoutSec 5 -ErrorAction Stop
        $status = [int]$res.StatusCode
    }
    catch {
        $status = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    }
    
    # output a formatted string to capture in variable $result
    "$status - $uri"
}

$result

#output to log file
$result | Export-Csv "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\Logs.csv"

#ping
$output = $()

foreach ($name in $names) {
    $results = @{ "Host Name" = $name }
    if (Test-Connection -Computername $name -Count 5 -ea 0) {
        $results["Results"] = "Up"
    }
    
    else {
        $results["Results"] = "Down"
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $results -OutVariable nameStatus
    $output += $nameStatus
}

$output | Export-Csv "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\hostname.csv"

#combine the 2 csvs into 1 excel file
$path = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop" #target folder
cd $path;
$csvs = Get-ChildItem .\*.csv
$csvCount = $csvs.Count
Write-Host "Detected the following CSV files: ($csvCount)"

foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    Write-Host " -"$csv.Name
}

Write-Host "--------------------"
$excelFileName = "daily $(get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy).xlsx"
Write-Host "Creating: $excelFileName"

foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    $csvPath = ".\" + $csv.Name
    $worksheetName = $csv.Name.Replace(".csv", "")
    Write-Host " - Adding $worksheetName to $excelFileName"
    Import-Csv -Path $csvPath | Export-Excel -Path $excelFileName -WorkSheetname $worksheetName
}

Write-Host "--------------------"
cd $path;
Get-ChildItem \* -Include \*.csv -Recurse | Remove-Item
Write-Host "Cleaning up"
```

---

Output in PowerShell

```
200 - https://chargebacks911.com/play-404/
200 - https://www.google.com/
500 - httpstat.us/500/

Host Name    Results

----------------

x.x.x.x    Down  
x.x.x.x Up  
Detected the following CSV files: (2)

- daily 26-03-2022.csv
- Logs.csv

--------------------

Creating: daily26-03-2022.xlsx

- Adding daily 26-03-2022 to daily26-03-2022.xlsx
- Adding Logs to daily26-03-2022.xlsx

--------------------

Cleaning up

\----------------------------------

result in excel

\#Hostname

Host Name   Results

x.x.x.x Down

x.x.x.x Up

\#Logs

Length

42

29

22
```

I would like to know

1. how to correct the output in "Logs" sheet
2. if there's anyway to simplify my script to make it cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You're asking for a review or refactoring of your complete script. I think that's not how SO is supposed be used. Instead you may focus on one particular issue and ask about a specific problem you have with it.

I will focus only on the part with the query of the status of your servers. You should stop using `Write-Host`. Instead you should take advantage of PowerShells uinique feature - working with rich and powerful objects instead of stupid text. ;-)
I'd approach the task of querying a bunch of computers like this:

```
$ComputernameList = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\hostnames.txt'

$Result =
foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputernameList) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        Online       = Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet
    }
}
$result
```

Now you have a PowerShell object you can pipe to `Export-Csv` for example or use it for further steps.

For example filter for the offline computers:

```
$result | Where-Object -Property Online -NE -Value $true
```

If you insist to have a visual control during the runtime of the script you may use [Write-Verbose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-7.2) or [Write-Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug?view=powershell-7.2). This way you can switch on the output if needed but omit it when the script runs unattended.